# Regex: Replace with value inside quotation marks and ignore if just quotation marks

Tags: regex

I have this:

`"test dd","test","","test","tes_d"`

I would like this:

`test dd,test,"",test,tes_d`

It works with `"([^"]*)"`, but it replaces third value (`""`) with empty string.

Comment: Do you have any values that might contain a quote (which is then probably escaped as ``\"`` or `""`)? Simple quote replacement would not be too kind on that.

Comment: Try looking for `("")|"([^"]+)"` and replace with `$1$2`, see https://regex101.com/r/fjKv7H/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
("")|"([^"]+)"
```

Replace with `$1$2`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fjKv7H/1).

*Details*

- `("")` - Group 1 (`$1`): `""` string
- `|`  - or
- `"([^"]+)"` - a `"`, then any one or more chars other than `"` (captured into Group 2, `$2`) and then a `"`.